# RxJs 6 : Manage array iteration and delay

Tags: rxjs, rxjs6

i need help on managing delay on an array iteration.

Regarding my https://jsfiddle.net/mlefree/vrL813j2/93/, two questions :

1. How to add delay on each iteration action ?
2. How to reduce all iteration computed values ?

```

```
...

const arrayAsObservable = of(null).pipe(
        delay(500),
        switchMap(_ => getObjectWithArrayInPromise()),
        map(val => {
            log('array', val);
            return (val.myArray);
        }),
        switchMap(val => from(val))
    );

const eachElementAsObservable = arrayAsObservable.pipe(
                delay(500), // Not working : we want to wait 500ms more for each value
        map(val => {
            log('value', val);
            return val ;
        }),
        switchMap(val => getNewValueInPromise(val)),
        map(val => {
        // Not working : why not all new values ?
            log('value after computing (KO)', val);
            return (val);
        })
     );

const summarizeAsObservable = eachElementAsObservable.pipe(
// Not working : we want to sum all new values
        map(val => { 
            log('value before reduce (KO)', val);
            return val ;
        }),
        reduce((a,b) => a + b)
);

summarizeAsObservable.subscribe(msg => {
    log('We did a total of (KO)', msg);
});
```

```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Overall the code is a bit too complex, there's a few lines become the root problem of your code.

The reason that you only receive one value after computing (KO) is you used `switchMap` which will unsubscribe the inner observable once the source emit, so you always get the last emitted value. I also change delay to `timer` and `mapTo` the emitted value

```
 const eachElementAsObservable = arrayAsObservable.pipe(

  concatMap(value => timer(1500).pipe(mapTo(value))), // Not working : we want to wait 500ms for each value
  map(val => {
    log('value', val);
    return val;
  }),
  mergeMap(val => from(getNewValueInPromise(val))),
  map(val => {

    // Not working : why not all new values ?
    console.log('value after computing (KO)', val);
    return (val);
  })
);
```

this is a updated fiddle https://jsfiddle.net/fancheung/vrL813j2/109/
The code is not fully working because you throw an error by reject in promise that will cause the observable to stop emitting, you will need to put a `catchError` somewhere in the stream

Comment: One remark, **concatMap** is probably better here due to possible memory leak ie. https://www.learnrxjs.io/operators/transformation/mergemap.html. => https://jsfiddle.net/mlefree/vrL813j2/147/